# Is there a comprehensive web source for a list of european union protections against aggresive contracts?

Tags: european-union, eula

Some time ago I found interesting information on the web about additional legal protections that customers from the European Union automatically have when signing up to various services (even services whose EULAs don't include these protections specifically like from companies in the US).

One such protection was a right of sale of purchased digital goods in which anyone who payed money in a single transaction to "purchase" the right to use a specific digital product (like a video game on Steam) is also granted the right, in the EU specifically, to later sale that game to someone else in exchange for money, enabling a sort of "transfer" of ownership despite this going against Steam's own terms of service. I also heard that this was used to apply to reselling of Windows product keys as well (again, against Microsoft's own wishes).

I've been wondering if there's a website (or book or any other source) that catalogues these additional protections that may invalidate some existing EULAs so that I can acquire a more comprehensive list of them instead of having to scavenge through legal documents from the EU to find them.